# Importing data from SQL to Excel adds apostrophe to string that begins with "="

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql, microsoft-excel-2013, import

I use MySQL for Excel, and I am trying to import data from MySQL. 
One of the cells (fields) in MySQL contains the following string:

```
='WW24'!E7
```

Excel, by default, adds an apostrophe at the beginning of the text in this cell.  How I can prevent Excel from doing this?

Comment: You mean as in execute the content of this very special cell?

Comment: I understand that you want to avoid having the apostrophe in front of the string, but what is the end goal you're looking for? Do you want that string to be interpreted by Excel as a formula?

Comment: yes. I want to get the function from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-import-options-advanced.html), the Advanced Options dialog (which apparently is available when importing table data with MySQL for Excel) contains the following option:

> Escape text values that start with "=" so Excel does not treat them as formulas

In your case, it seems this option should be disabled (i.e. unchecked).

Comment: I have already tried it. However, with no success.

Comment: OK, but that information should be included in your question, along with anything else you have tried.